# Display Flex with break tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm developing a rich text box. Not yet developed as editable DOM. Been stucked into the initial stage. I have mentioned it as an `Flex` element. On `cmd+enter` i will be adding an `<br>` tag. I have an `<a>` tag as an direct child to the `Flex` Element. Adding the `<a>` tag makes that element to get away from the alignment. How to make the `<a>` element to be aligned (Should be aligned one after another). If i add an extra `div` i get it fixed. Refer below

```css
.my-inline-element {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-inline-element">
    <div class="extraDiv">
      item
      <br>
      <a href="3">Item2</a>
      <br>
      sample3
      <br>
      sample4
      <br>
    </div>
 </div>
```

On removing DOM with the `extraDiv` class makes the alignment noisy. Refer below

```css
.my-inline-element {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-inline-element">
      item
      <br>
      <a href="3">Item2</a>
      <br>
      sample3
      <br>
      sample4
      <br>
 </div>
```

Is there is any possibilities to achieve without adding an `extraDiv`. Also i don't Flex property to be removed

Comment: use `flex-direction: column`?

Comment: adding flex-direction renders extra space @kukkuz

Comment: I guess using the `extraDiv` is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> By adding another CSS class to your parent DIV or mentioned the child element as display:block will help to sort out your issue, Lets
> ```
>
> give a try...
>
> ```
> https://jsfiddle.net/jk2sy1f0/
>
> > .my-inline-element {    border: 2px solid red;    display: flex;   
> > height:100px; }
> > 
> > .lineBreak{
> >     display:block; }
> > 
> > <div class="my-inline-element lineBreak">   item   <br>   <a
> > href="3">Item2</a>   <br>sample3   <br>sample4   <br> </div>
> >
> ```

Comment: I dont want it to be block element. I want it as flex element

Answer (score -2):

```
.my-inline-element {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height:100px;
  flex-direction: column nowrap;
}
```

Click [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)